# Boost: Why is toolset listed in ~/user-config.jam not available to ./b2?

Tags: c++, macos, boost

In my attempt to answer my own question [Clang linker reports "symbol not found", despite 'nm -m' revealing that the name exists in a library that is being linked against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599721/clang-linker-reports-symbol-not-found-despite-nm-m-revealing-that-the-name), I have discovered links that indicate that I must build Boost on OS X so that it *explicitly* uses Clang and links to `libc++` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081818/linking-troubles-with-boostprogram-options-on-osx-using-llvm), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp), and [here](http://cplusplusmusings.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/clang-and-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x/).

Following the steps indicated (with the help of additional googling to assist with/confirm the process of editing `user-config.jam`, placing it in my home directory, and other necessary steps), I have added the following lines to my `~/user-config.jam` file:

```
using clanglibcpp : 11
    : "/usr/bin/clang++"
    : <cxxflags>"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" <linkflags>"-stdlib=libc++"
    ;
```

I have then run `./b2` from the `$BOOST_ROOT` directory:

`./b2 toolset=clanglibcpp-11 --with-filesystem variant=release link=static threading=multi`

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I receive the following error:

`ERROR: rule "clanglibcpp.init" unknown in module "toolset"`

I have confirmed that `/usr/bin/clang++` exists at the path indicated (it does).  I have also tried adding the above lines to `$BOOST_ROOT/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam` (no luck).  I have also tried running `./bootstrap.sh` from the boost root directory, as well as running `./b2 --clean`.  No luck.

What am I supposed to do to actually get the toolset in `user-config.jam` to take effect for my Boost build on OS X?

Comment: I'm not sure, and sadly I can't check right now, but can you try using: `using clang : libcpp11 : "/usr/bin/clang++" : <cxxflags>"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" <linkflags>"-stdlib=libc++" ;` and then invoking b2 like this: `./b2 toolset=clang-libcpp11 --with-filesystem variant=release link=static threading=multi`

Comment: It worked!  Why does this make a difference?  I thought that this entry in `user-config.jam` **DEFINES** the toolset; but the fact that this change worked implies that the toolset name (`clang`) must already exist, and the entry here just adds a different variant of that toolset.  In any case, please post this as an answer so that I can accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: @cv_and_he I forgot to tag you in my comment... see comment above.

Comment: Glad it helped, but I don't know enough to put an answer. Hopefully someone more experienced will be able to give an explanation.

Comment: @cv_and_he hmmm - I understand.  But, it actually answers the question.  If you don't put it as the answer, I will (just so it's noted for future users that the question *is* answered) - and I'd rather give you the credit.  Thanks again!

Comment: @DanNissenbaum according to Boost.Build reference, the first identifier is a "tool" name, so one can only select one of the [built-in tools](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/extending/tools.html) (or provide support [for a new one](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/extending/tools.html)).

Answer (score 1):

***@llonesmiz answer that worked to @Dan Nissenbaum:***

I'm not sure, and sadly I can't check right now, but can you try using:

```
using clang : libcpp11 
    : "/usr/bin/clang++"
    : <cxxflags>"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" <linkflags>"-stdlib=libc++"
    ;
```

and then invoking b2 like this:

```
./b2 toolset=clang-libcpp11 --with-filesystem variant=release link=static threading=multi
```